# how to solve "degree of separation from kevin bacon" in cypher ne04j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am unable to solve the degree of separation from Kevin bacon. i have the idea but i am unable to implement it in cypher. any help would be appreciated. the degree should be at most 5.

Answer (score 4):

In the Neo4j 2.0 browser you can play the movie mini-graph tutorial to do the Bacon Path.

Get all people 1-5 hops away from Kevin Bacon.

```
MATCH (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*1..5]-(hollywood)
RETURN DISTINCT hollywood
```

Get the shortest path between Kevin Bacon and Meg Ryan.

```
MATCH p=shortestPath(
  (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"})
)
RETURN p
```

In the Neo4j 2.0 browser, in the console window, run `:play movie graph`

Comment: what is hollywood? is it "movie" or a person? i tried your query as is, it gave me zero rows

Comment: i changed the query to `MATCH (bacon:ACTOR {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[r:ACTS_IN*1..4]-(hollywood)
    RETURN DISTINCT hollywood limit 100` it gives me unknown error

Comment: When you get an unknown error in the browser it means that your query timeout after 60 seconds. The query continues to run on the Neo4j server but the browser has a 60 second timeout. Use the Neo4j shell, `neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell`. Try the same query but with a `;` at the end of the return.

Answer (score -2):

```
MATCH (bacon:ACTOR {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[r:ACTS_IN]-(m:MOVIES)<-[*1..5]-(hollywood:ACTOR)
RETURN DISTINCT hollywood.name limit 100
```

This is what i thought would be the correct answer